# Datepicker doesn't load on Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, datepicker

I'm trying to make a datepicker for my application. The frontend is written in Backbone.js and the templates are written in Jade.
Here I include some libraries on top of JS:

```
    'jquery',
    'jqueryUI',
    'jqueryTouch',
    'bootstrap',
    'bootstrapSelect',
    'bootstrapSwitch',
    'flatuiCheckbox',
    'flatuiRadio',
    'flatuiTags',
    'flatuiplaceholder',
    'flatuiApp',
    'woomark',
    'backbone_validation'
```

Here in the code I append a div and an input text field where you should be able to see the datepicker when you click on it:

```
$('#main-view').append("<label id=logLabel></label>");
                $('#logLabel').append("Start Date:<div class='form-group'>" +
                "<div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-btn'>" +
                "<button type='button' class='btn'><span class='fui-calendar'></span></button>" +
                "</span><input id='datepicker-01' type='text' value='15 October, 2014' class='form-control datepicker hasDatepicker'></div></div>");
                var datepickerSelector = '.datepicker';
                **$(datepickerSelector).datepicker({**
                    showOtherMonths: true,
                    selectOtherMonths: true,
                    dateFormat: "d MM, yy",
                    yearRange: '-1:+1'
                }).prev('.btn').on('click', function (e) {
                    e && e.preventDefault();
                    $($(datepickerSelector)).focus();
                });
                $.extend($.datepicker, {
                    _checkOffset: function (inst, offset) {
                        return offset
                    }
                });
```

When I try to run the program and click on the datepicker I got an error on the line I made with bold. I have checked the libraries and the paths and they are correct. Where could the problem be?

Comment: unfortunately I couldn't post a screenshot due to lack of reputation, hope the description above is accurate enough

Comment: be sure u call JQ plugin after Backbone View render()

Comment: What error do you get? Is there a `.datepicker` in the DOM when you expect it to be?